# Send mail with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, email

Have question about mail sending through bash script about disc space.

Every 30,59 minutes crontab start bash script which sending email if disc space reaches 90%. Now 2 filesystems reaches 90% and every crontab start i get same email about same issue. How to update script to don't send me the same email , but just if the disc space changes in 90-100% limits?

thanks

```
df -h | grep -v '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output;
do
echo $output
partition=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')
if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ] ; then
echo "Running out of space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on server $(hostname), $(date)" | \
mail -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep%" $ADMIN
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
report=$(
    df -hP | awk -v alert="$ALERT" -v h="$(hostname)" -v d="$(date)" '
        (!/^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom/) && $5 > alert {
            printf "Running out of space \"%s %d\" on server %s, %s\n", $1, $5, h, d
        }
    '
)
if [[ "$report" ]]; then
    mail -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep%" "$ADMIN" <<<"$report"
fi
```

I pushed all the logic into awk, and collected all the results before sending a single email.

This does not prevent email if the usage is *still* over 90%. For that, you'd have to write the current results to a file, and on the next iteration read the file and check for changes.

Answer (score 0):

Store the previous percentage of used space in a file, read it into an array, and write the new percentages in the end.

```
#!/bin/bash

## File with partitions and percent full
last_usep=/path/file

## If the file exists, read lines into array
if [[ -f $last_usep ]] ; then

    ## Associative array
    declare -A map_usep

    while read line ; do

        partition=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
        usep=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
        map_usep[$partition]=$usep   

    done < $last_usep
fi

## Check partitions
df -h | \
grep -v '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | \
awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | \
while read output; do

    usep=$(echo $output | awk '{print $1}')
    partition=$(echo $output | awk '{print $2}')

    ## If "usep" has not changed, skip to next iteration. Otherwise, store the new percentage
    if [[ $usep== ${map_usep[$partition]} ]] ; then 
        continue
    else
        map_usep[$partition]=$usep
    fi

    if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ] ; then

        echo "Running out of space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on server $(hostname), $(date)" | \
    mail -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep%" $ADMIN

    fi
done

## Update the file with new percentages
\rm $last_usep
touch $last_usep
for partition in "${!usep[@]}" ; do
    echo $partition ${usep[$partition]} >> $last_usep
done
```